# convert all times to 0:00

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How would I convert all dates which are currently YYYY-MM-DD Time, where the Time is 00:00.

Below is my code and I attach a pic

[image]

```
    select* from(SELECT
    Date,
    Depot,
     Vehicle,
     Quantity as [Ltrs],
     OdoReadingMiles,
     LAG(OdoReadingMiles, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle ORDER BY Date) AS previousmileage
     ,OdoReadingMiles-LAG(OdoReadingMiles, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle ORDER BY Date) as [Miles]
     ,(OdoReadingMiles-LAG(OdoReadingMiles, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle ORDER BY Date)) / (Quantity/4.544) as [MPG]
     ,case when (OdoReadingMiles-LAG(OdoReadingMiles, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle ORDER BY Date)) / (Quantity/4.544) not between 2 and 10 then 1 else 0 end as [Anomaly]
     FROM [Fleet].[DwhTriscanChargeouts] )as x
     WHERE x.Anomaly=0
     ORDER BY 2,1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you areusing.

Comment: If the time portion isn't important, use `date`.

Comment: On a different note: [Bad habits to kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can just convert to a date:

```
select convert(date, datetimecol) as datecol
```

It is unclear what columns you are talking about, so the above generically answers your question.

Comment: I am talking about the date column. Your code works, but removes the time. I want to keep the time and set it to midnight (00:00)?

Comment: @AmmarWahid . . . You can convert back to a `datetime`:  `convert(datetime, convert(date, datecol))`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert first to date, and then back to datetime. The time part will be lost leaving it to 00:00

```
select convert(datetime, convert(date, datetimecol)) as datetimecol
```